# How to access value of a routing parameter in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-component, react-routing

I want to have a 'dynamic route' for a section of my app, which was done like this:

```
<Route path="path(/:id)" component={Component} />
```

So far this works, but in Component I would like to access the value of id because it changes a bunch of things depending on which it is. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component, you would access this via `props`.

```
this.props.params.id
```

Here is the guide from react-router that goes into more detail as well.
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/06-params

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for.